# Scala switch which continue matching next cases after successful match

Tags: java, scala, switch-statement

How can I do in scala switch statement which after performing one case block start perform another case block. (in java: cases without break).

```
switch(step) {
    case 0: do something;
    case 1: do something more;
    case 2: etc...;
            break;
    default: do something else;
}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: what is wrong with this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: Sorry i need write this code in scala.

Comment: I don't think it's possible

Comment: Why do you need to write it in scala? Maybe if you expand on what you are trying to achieve people can suggest good ways to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case you can't use `0 | 1 | 2` you could use a list of actions as workaround like this:

```
def switch[T](i: T)(actions: (T, () => Unit)*)(default: => Unit) = {
  val acts = actions.dropWhile(_._1 != i).map{_._2}
  if (acts.isEmpty) default
  else acts.foreach{_()}
}

def myMethod(i: Int): Unit = 
  switch(i)(
    0 -> {() => println("do 0")},
    1 -> {() => println("do 1")},
    2 -> {() =>
      println("do 2")
      return // instead of break
    },
    3 -> {() => println("do 3")}
  )(default = println("do default"))


myMethod(1)
// do 1
// do 2

myMethod(3)
// do 3    

myMethod(5)
// do default
```

Answer (score 5):

```
def myMatch(step: Int): Int = step match {
  case 0 => { dosomething(); myMatch(step + 1) }
  case 1 => { dosomethingMore(); myMatch(step + 1) }
  case 2 => etc()
  case _ => doSomethingElse();
}
```

If the performance isn't critical, this should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

In Scala, there is no switch case fall through. You can do or (`|`) instead:

```
step match {
  case 0 | 1 | 2 => something
  ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry i edited my question. I need this switch (without breaks) write in scala.

Comment: I am not very experienced in scala, but added a solution for scala which I know. I am not sure if there are better ways to do it.